# Returning an initialized structure from local scope unexpectedly works in C11

Tags: c, oop, design-patterns, embedded, local

In our code base, I encountered some C code that I am not able to understand why it works.

Pretty sure implements some pattern found on the internet. Ideally this code should emulate some object-oriented pattern from C++, and it is used to create queues.

Here is (part of) the code for the declaration (.h) of the queue module:

```
struct Queue_t
{
  uint8_t         Queue[MAX_QUEUE_SIZE];
  uint32_t        Head;
  uint32_t        Tail;
  uint16_t        Counter;
  Queue_return_t  (*Push)(struct Queue_t * Queue, uint8_t * NewElement, uint16_t ElementSize);
  Queue_return_t  (*Pop)(struct Queue_t * Queue, Queue_Element_t *RetElement);
  Queue_return_t  (*Flush)(struct Queue_t * Queue);
};

extern const struct QueueClass {
        struct Queue_t (*new)( void );
} Queue_t;

struct Queue_t new( void );
```

Here is (part of) the code for the implementation (.c) of the queue module:

```
struct Queue_t new( void )
{
  struct Queue_t NewQueue;

[...]
  NewQueue.Push = &QueueManager_Push;
  NewQueue.Pop = &QueueManager_Pop;
  NewQueue.Flush = &QueueManager_Flush;
  return NewQueue;
}

const struct QueueClass Queue_t={.new=&new};
```

then the usage in the code is the following:

```
struct Queue_t Output_Queue;
Output_Queue = Queue_t.new();
[...]
RetQueue =  Output_Queue.Pop(&Output_Queue,Output_Queue_elem);
```

Now, we switched to a more straightforward queue implementation.
Still I am not able to grasp what is going on in this code.

As stated in the title, my problem is in the "new" function, where a `struct Queue_t` is declared in a local scope and then returned.

As further information, in the project that used this "queue" module there was no dynamic memory allocation, hence no heap, free or malloc.

Everything worked *really* smooth, I would expect the code to crash as soon as the stack for the referenced object is freed and the pointer to the structure is accessed.

Also, the compiler used was IAR  and is not complaining (this code was used on a uC).

Maybe the `const` qualifier is involved?

Any hint on what is going on?

Comment: It is okay to return a local struct. The struct will be copied to the LHS struct in the caller The thing that causes undefined behaviour is returning a pointer to a local struct, because now you have a "stale"  pointer that points to invalid memory.

Comment: Why do you expect your compiler to complain? If you return a struct, its value is copied to the caller

Comment: This is not unexpected. You are returning by value, so the structure will be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly legal to return a *value* declared inside a function. The problem only arises if you return a *pointer* to a value declared inside a function, and then try to access it.

The `new()` function you show is equivalent to:

```c
int foo(void) {
    int a = 123;
    return a;
}
```

There is no problem here, you're returning a value which is *copied* to the destination when doing:

```c
int x;
x = foo(); // copy happens here
```

Using `x` after this is *not* accessing the (now vanished) stack of `foo`, since `x` is defined outside `foo` and was copied when the function returned.

Doing this with a `struct` is no different, a `struct` is still treated as a single value, the only real difference is in the generated machine code, since copying a structure takes more effort (you need to copy each field).

The problem, again, only arises when you return a pointer to a locally defined variable and try using it outside:

```c
int *foo(void) {
    int a = 123;
    return &a;     // never do this!
} 

int main(void) {
    int *x;
    x = foo();
    return *x;     // OUCH!
}
```

Now *dereferencing* `x` (both for reading and for writing) means trying to access the (now vanished) stack of `foo`, and this is of course a problem.

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for your reply. Correct, I didn't think of it as a legit returned variable, I was thinking of pointers.